# HTTPS on localhost for OAuth for a desktop application

Tags: javascript, express, https, oauth, electron

I am creating a desktop application that using Spotify's oauth api. I am using the implicit grant flow described here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit_grant_flow

My idea is to have an "Authenticate" button, that you click and it opens your browser. You login/approve the connection with Spotify. Then it sends you to a redirect url.

I want to set this redirect url to 127.0.0.1:58212 or some port on the loopback device.

My question is, should I use https for this?

I am leaning towards yes. One because the access token needs to be secure, and I believe other users on the system could potentially read the message when it is sent, and two because in the time it took the user to log in, someone could have taken over the port.

So I want SSL for encryption of the message, and I want to ensure I am actually talking to my app.

How do I generate certificates in this situation? I think each instance of the application needs to have its own certificate, and I need to somehow inform the computer to trust that certificate during the lifetime of the application.

I could also generate the certificate during installation, and do some step during installation that makes the system trust that certificate.

Am I thinking about this the correct way, or am I going about this all wrong?

I am using electron and express in JavaScript to write my application.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to securely use Oauth with installed applications such as desktop applications is to use the Oauth 2 flow for installed applications. But this option would have to be implemented by the service provider. Google provides for this option.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app

Unfortunately, many services do not implement OAuth2.

To use Oauth 1.0 with installed applications, instead of returning to a callback_url, the service provider displays the auth code to the user which the user can then copy and paste to the desktop application. Check out Trello Ouath integration which allows for this.

The Web Api flow that you are trying to achieve will not work in the case of desktop apps. The redirect uri 127.0.0.1:port is your local uri. The service provider will need, at the very least, your public ip to redirect the flow back to your system.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, for a Desktop or a native app it is much better to implement the Oauth authorization code flow.  The implicit grant is intended to be used on a device browser and not on a Web View.

If your app uses a Web Service to connect, your Web Service needs a redirect URL that uses https.  Luckily most hosting platforms like Heroku provide this to you for free (otherwise you need to buy an SSL certificate which might be a lot of work).

On the authorization code flow, a token doesn't need to see the client, it is all stored in the backend.

Most services allow you to test on localhost with http.
I wrote a [tutorial](https://github.com/rubenrincon/dbximgdemo/tree/master#4--oauth-with-authorization-code-grant-flow) that could give you some guidance on the flow.